# PyAutoGui кликает не туда

Tags: python, pyautogui

Вот какая ситуация.
Если изменить разрешение экрана с 1920x1080 на любое другое уже после запуска скрипта, то `pyautogui` кликает не на те коордиинаты. Например, если изменить разрешение на 1366x768, то вместо `x = 940 y = 227` клик будет по координатам `x = 755 y = 186`. Пример кода:

```
import pyautogui as pag

pag.click(940, 227)
```

Однако клик происходит совершенно по другим координатам (скрин ниже).

[image: Координаты клика]

Проблема в том, что разрешение экрана меняет игра, т.к. в настройках системы указано `1920x1080`, а в самой игре: `1366x768`. Однако все, что работает с координатам - работает корректно, кроме библиотеки `pyautogui`. Есть ли какая-нибудь возможность это исправить ?

**UPDATE:**
Походу я понял, почему `pyautogui` кликает не туда. Он неправильно определяет разрешение. Вместо `1366x768` он видит почему-то `1708x960`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использовал такой код:

```
while True:
    print(pyautogui.size())
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: `def click(x, y): pag.click(int(x * 1708 / 1920), int(y * 960 / 1080))` — костыль.

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, ну, собственно, примерно так и решил. Написал ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Покопавшись в `pyautogui` я выяснил, что текущее разрешение экрана на *Windows* получается с помощью

`ctypes.windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(0)`

и

`ctypes.windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(1)`

К сожалению, я так и не понял, почему разрешение, которое определяет `ctypes` не совпадает с тем, что установлено в игре. Смею предположить, что это может быть из-за разных соотношений сторон у разных разрешений (хоть я и меняю разрешение экрана, однако физически экран у меня не меняется). Однако это не применимо к паре разрешений `1920х1080` и `1366х768`, ведь оба этих разрешений имеют соотношение сторон `16:9`.

Но все-таки есть решение, которое подошло в моем случае:

```
import ctypes
import random
import pyautogui as pag

def create_odds(w, h):
    # w - заданная мной ширина экрана (игрой)
    # h - тоже самое, но с высотой

    global windows_w, windows_h

    windows_w = ctypes.windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(0)
    windows_h = ctypes.windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(1)
    # windows_w/h - ширина и высота экрана, определенная с помощью ctypes

    x_odd = round(windows_w/w, 2)
    y_odd = round(windows_h/h, 2)
    # создаем коэффициенты разницы между данным мной разрешением и разрешением, полученным с помощью ctypes


x = random.randint(0, 1366)
y = random.randint(0, 768)
# Генерируем случайные координаты для клика

create_odds(1366, 768) #  создаем коэффициенты

pag.click(round(x*x_odd), round(y*y_odd)) 
#Кликаем по координатам с учетом разницы.
```